# Adding header based on cookies

Tags: nginx

I want to add a request header indicating whether a request appears to be coming from a desktop client or a mobile client.

I tried adding this in a server block

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* 'mobile|phone') && ($http_user_agent !~* 'ipad') {
  proxy_set_header       X-Device-Category "mobile";
} else {
  proxy_set_header       X-Device-Category "desktop";
}
```

But `nginx -t` responds `"if" directive is not allowed here`

I can grasp from various posts that `if` doesn't work the way you'd imagine in Nginx, but I'm uncertain about other ways to approach this.

Moving this simple logic into the application is not an option here, because Nginx will need this as caching key.

Comment: `if` can only be placed in `server` or `location` blocks. You appear to have placed it somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via the map directive instead of if.

```
map $http_user_agent $device_category {
    default "desktop";
    "~*ipad" "desktop";
    "~*mobile|phone" "mobile";
}
```

Then in your location block:

```
proxy_set_header X-Device-Category $device_category;
```